# Expectation of kernel density estimators using sharpened data

Tags: probability, kernel-smoothing, density-estimation

My question regards the proof of the bias of the kernel density estimator obtained using "sharpened" data. The method comes from the paper by [Choi and Hall (1999)](https://academic.oup.com/biomet/article/86/4/941/276258?login=true).

Specifically, assume $X_1, \dots, X_n$ are iid sample from some nice density $f$. Consider the mapping
$$
\varphi_n(x) = x + \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i - x)K(h^{-1}(X_i - x))}{\sum_{i=1}^nK(h^{-1}(X_i - x)))},
$$
where $K$ is some nice kernel probability density function. This is effectively the Nadaraya-Watson (NW) estimator where the data is both the independent and response variable.

Now the authors claimed that if the "sharpened" data $\hat{X_j} = \varphi(X_j)$ are used to construct the density estimation of $f$, it then has reduced (asymptotic) bias compared to the the density estimation using the raw data $X_j$.

What I am confused about is their proof of this bias reduction as it seems extremely heuristic and handwavy. First of all, they showed that
$$
E(\lim_{n\to\infty}\varphi_n(x)) = x + \frac{h^2f'(x)}{f(x)}\kappa + o(h^2),
$$
where $\kappa = \int u^2K(u)du$. This is rather a standard application of the asymptotic bias of the general NW estimator where the regression function is actually the identity function (since the response and the independent variables are the same). Based on this, the authors then proceeds to compute the (asymptotic) expectation of the "sharpened" kernel estimator. However, they claimed the following:
$$
E(\lim_{n\to\infty}K(h^{-1}(\varphi_n(X_j) - x))) = \int K\left(\frac{x - u - h^2f'(x)/f(x)\kappa}{h}\right)f(u)du + o(h^2).
$$
It seems that the authors directly plugged in the asymptotic **expectation** of $\varphi_n(x)$ in to the above while in theory it is not what we should do since $\lim_{n\to\infty}\varphi_n(X_i)$ is still clearly a random variable, but the authors simply replaced it by a deterministic quantity.

However, after some thought on my own, we can still have
$$
\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, \ \lim_{n\to\infty}\varphi_n(x) = x + \frac{h^2f'(x)}{f(x)}\kappa + o(h^2) \ a.s. 
$$
using SLLN. But this is still not enough since even though the above holds for all real number $x$, there is no gurantee that it holds for a random variable $X_j$ so that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\varphi_n(X_j) = X_j + \frac{h^2f'(X_j)}{f(X_j)}\kappa + o(h^2)$. I have struggled for days trying to figure out their reasoning but I just don't see it. Any help on this would be very much appreciated!